# Rename all file names in a directory using datagridview column value

Tags: c#, datagridview, file-rename

I have a datagridview

```
ID     Name
-----------
1      ABC    
2      DEF    
3      XYZ
```

I have 3 files in a directory

```
ABC.csv
DEF.csv
XYZ.csv
```

How do I loop through the file names and rename them according to their ID, so that they become

```
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
```

Here's my code but I do not know to do the retrieve the ID from datagridview. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you. :)

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirCSV);
FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
{
    try
    {
        File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceDirCSV), "???"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this code snippet?

Comment: @shree.pat18 if I get you right, I am calling this with a button click.

Comment: ButtonClick inside Grid or Outside of Grid?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE I believe outside grid. The code snippet is the only code in my button click function `private void btn_rename_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like this:

```
        string sourceDir = "D:\\Temp\\";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);
        string newFileName = "";
        string oldFileName = "";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            newFileName = sourceDir + row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString() + ".csv";
            oldFileName = sourceDir + row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString() + ".csv";

            if (File.Exists(oldFileName))
            {
                File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName);
            }                
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try with the Following:

Loop through all rows of `DataGrid`:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string colVal=row.Cells(1).Value.ToString();
    foreach (string currFilename in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.csv").Select(Path.GetFileName))
    {
      //Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name): this will get file name without extension
       if(colVal.Equals(currFilename))
       {
        //rename file here
       }
    }
}
```

**Please make changes according to your requirement dont use "as is".**

hope this helps you!

Comment: Although not exactly work, this helps too! I learned that I need to loop through datagrid instead of files :D Thank you!